# How to define asterisk custom queue ring strategy?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I have a queue 0 and 2 extensions 100 and 101. The manager is assigned to an order in admin panel. So if the client calls us he should go directly to the assigned manager.

I need to find a place to change the queue agent selection logic. I've tried to change the extension dialup plan, but agent is already selected at this moment. As far as I understand the queue looks at agent priority and takes agent on the top. So I need to add a check if this is a manager's client -> set the highest priority to receive this call.

Could someone advise what is a correct place to adjust agent selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change priority and penalty values using variables

```
${QUEUE_PRIO} Queue priority
${QUEUE_MAX_PENALTY} Maximum member penalty allowed to answer caller
```

No, you can't do that via web withut hacks.

Comment: But when I need to set these variables? The idea is to make a request via curl and get an extension priority for each call. If a caller is associated with an agent - set the highest priority to this agent. The priority of each agent should depend on the incoming call number.

Comment: you should set that in dialplan before start of app_queue. No, you can't change priority of *AGENT*, but you can can select min/max penalty. Anything above that should be addressed using custom code.

Comment: can I set a penalty for each queue member for each call? I'm using FreePBX, could you advise where can I find peace of code that starts a queue?

Comment: Maybe via realtime, but highly unlikly. Was not possible. No, you definitly can't do something like that without create custom freepbx module. "Piece of code" in freepbx called queue module/queue_prio module. Code in /var/www/html/admin/modules/queues/ but you can't just change it, it will warn about altered module. Check how to write hooks on freepbx dev site